# Is it possible to add Postgres extensions to AWS Aurora?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, amazon-rds-aurora

I am trying to futureproof a Postgres database so it can be transferred to AWS Aurora.

I am using the guide extension `uuid-ossp`.

Is it possible to add PostGres extensions to AWS Aurora?

In particular, I am interested in whether the extension `uuid-ossp` can be used in Aurora.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can create Postgres extensions in AWS Aurora Postgres. Yes, the extension `uuid-ossp` can be used in Aurora.

To get supported extension list in your AWS Aurora Postgres version, run this query:

```
SHOW rds.extensions;
```

or

```
select * from  pg_available_extensions;
```

And also check out [PostgreSQL Extensions and Modules Supported on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions)  in the Amazon Relational Database Service User Guide for the list of extensions supported in AWS Aurora Postgres based on Postgres versions.

There is no difference in the extension usage for both community Postgres and Aurora Postgres if extension installed on the server. For `uuid-ossp` usage, please refer to [F.44. uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) in the PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: I set up a test aurora postgres instance and was able to add this extension successfully